# Login to website authenticated with ADFS ,WS - Trust ,SAML token using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, adfs, ws-trust

I want to login to a website using PHP Curl for which I have username and password.After research I have found that the website is using WS-Trust and ADFS for authentication and authorizing.Here User's browser is redirected to IDP(ADFS) and redirected back with SAML assertion security token.

After reading this post on http://leandrob.com/2012/02/request-a-token-from-adfs-using-ws-trust-from-ios-objective-c-iphone-ipad-android-java-node-js-or-any-platform-or-language/ .I have tried to make request by creating SOAP Envelope for getting security token but I am confused what will be the endpoint on which I will be sending this request. In leandrob.com post it is mentioned to use "https://[server]/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed" as endpoint .I tried sending request to this endpoint but I got blank page as output.

I need to send request and get security token back.Could anyone please explain what URL need to be considered as endpoint for logging into WS-Trust and ADFS authenticated website.